# Report Viewer showing session expired message on pagination

Tags: c#, silverlight, reportviewer

I have a microsoft report viewer inside silverlight application. The report has more than 1 page of results.

I have session set to readonly in this page, this is to avoid iis requests stuck issue caused by multiple requests with same session id

Now my issue is that, when I click on the second page in the report, I am getting a session expired message. This only happens in the silverlight application. When I copy the report url to the browser, it works fine.

Also in silverlight application if I set the Session.Abandon before logging in to the app, the pagination works for report even though the  Session.Abandon is not hit on Page.postback.

Can you please provide a solution for this.